# In series RLC circuit, does increasing capacitance value really make the circuit more inductive circuit?

Tags: passive-networks

This seems very counter intuitive to me. How can increasing capacitance value make the circuit more inductive ? The math tells me so :

If \$C\$ increases then \$X_c = \dfrac{1}{\omega C}\$ decreases, so the circuit becomes more inductive.

[image]

But I've heard that factories that use heavy motors have a large \$X_L\$. For this reason they need to increase \$X_C\$ so that \$X_L = X_C\$. To increase \$X_C\$ they seem to "add" capacitors. But adding capacitors actually decreases \$X_C\$ right ? \$X_C \propto \dfrac{1}{C}\$. How does this work ?

---

Definitions :
\$X_C\gt X_L\$  : more capacitive circuit

\$X_L\gt X_C\$  : more inductive circuit

Comment: Depends how you add them!  Think about how capacitance gets bigger.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Ty Capacitance gets big when added in parallel. But lets say we don't have any capacitors in the circuit and we have all inductors. Then \$C=0\$ implies \$X_c = \infty\$. How do we make sense of this ?

Comment: Then your circuit is inductive.  Power is going back and forth between source and inductor.  Add any capacitor and now some of that power goes between capacitor and inductor.

Comment: Also to fix the power factor they could add a very tiny capacitor in series with the motor as \$X_c \propto \dfrac{1}{C}\$. But this doesn't seem to be the case.. they are adding lots of large capacitances..

Comment: With heavy motors, you aren't increasing *series* capacitance.

Comment: If you add a capacitor in series, it will take away the voltage of the load (motor) and the load may not work.  Add C in parallel and motor works put source provides less current.

Comment: Oh, but they do connect the capacitor banks in series with the motor right ? @BrianDrummond

Comment: Always in parallel for power factor correction

Comment: OMG! Okay I see my mistake, Let me think again!

Comment: For pawer factor correction? No they don't, as I said - the capacitors are connected in parallel.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it yet. Suppose in the given series RLC circuit \$C = 10^{-100}F\$ , \$L = 1 mH\$, \$R = 1\$ and \$\omega = 300\$. Now clearly \$X_C\gt X_L\$ and the circuit is more capacitive by definition. How is this possible ?

Comment: The definition is throwing me off, how can having less capacitance make the circuit more capacitive..

Comment: Whether the circuit is inductive, capacitive or *resistive* defends on the values of f, L & C.

Comment: Capacitive reactance is not C.  You stated their inverse relationship.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I've never said Capacitive reactance is C

Comment: Here are the definitions
$$$$
 \$X_c\gt X_L\$ : more capacitive circuit  $$$$
 \$X_L\gt X_C\$ : more inductive circuit

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I've updated the question with these definitions. I hope this question makes some sense now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With series components the component that presents the highest impedance IS the dominant factor that determines overall impedance. For instance 1 ohm in series with 1000 ohms is still largely 1000 ohms.

A large value capacitor has a small value impedance hence, in a series circuit, as the capacitor value rises, it's dominance becomes less and less.

Opposite for a parallel combinations of components; lowest dominates.

Comment: Ohk.. As the capacitance decreases, the capacitor acts more closely to an "open" circuit, so more voltage drops across it. So far I've been wrongly replacing the capacitor with a "short", so the confusion. Your answer is perfect. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your capacitor here, instead. This is how facilities with large inductive loads implement power factor correction. (at least, passive PFC. Active PFC is another question entirely.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frUsc7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>